# Android Proto Datastore: Could not get unknown property 'source' for generate-proto-generateProductionDebugProto of type ...DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, protocol-buffers, datastore, android-jetpack-datastore

As per Proto DataStore codelab get exception while building the project

Android studio giraffe 2022.3.1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> **Could not get unknown property 'source' for generate-proto-generateProductionDebugProto of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update to the following code

```
plugins {
   ...
   id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.4"
}
```

And dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0"
}
```

And

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.8.0'
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().configureEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option "lite"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```